# Divisibilty and eulers thereom

Tags: number-theory

if $\gcd(a,b)=1$

is it true that,
$$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}=1\mod ab$$

I think the answer is yes, but I am not exactly sure about my reasoning

$a^{\phi(b)}=1\mod b$

and $b^{\phi(a)}=1\mod a$

by Euler's theorem.

The question asks if

$$ab| a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}-1$$

So what would a better way of seeing this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly done. Note that by $\text{CRT}$, all you have to note now is the fact that $$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)} \equiv  b^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1\pmod a$$$$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)} \equiv  a^{\phi(b)}\equiv 1\pmod b$$
From Euler's Theorem. So we can conclude $$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1\pmod {ab}$$
As $\gcd(a,b)=1$.